# Sign in page for custom admin model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I'm starting out with *ActiveAdmin*, and I already have a model for users and it's already hooked up with the other models. So I want to use it as the model for admin accounts.

Can anyone guide me trough the set up of *ActiveAdmin* using `--skip-users`?

The main problem is with login page, because I'd like to have it as the one, that  *ActiveAdmin* provides. Also what else I should look for when I try to make *ActiveAdmin* to function as it's natively designed and work with my custom user model

Comment: Is your User model generated by devise?

Comment: @Salil No, it's just a plain _ActiveRecord_ subclass with `login` `password_digest` and `has_secure_password` helper

Comment: You may find this blog post useful - http://dan.doezema.com/2012/02/how-to-implement-a-single-user-model-with-rails-activeadmin-and-devise/